# Convert 2 collections into a Map

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 `List`s as `List<String> a` and `List<String> b` of equal size.

What is the most efficient way to create a `Map<String, String>` in Java 8 using lambdas or something else where `List<String> a` are the keys and `List<String> b` are the values?

The Java 7 way is as follows:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    map.put(a.get(i), b.get(i));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is no `zip` operation on `Stream` (and no `Pair` class), a simple solution is to use an `IntStream` and loop over the indexes of each `List`.

```
Map<String, String> map =
    IntStream.range(0, a.size()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(a::get, b::get));
```

Alternatively, you can use the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library which offers a `zip` method and have:

```
Map<String, String> map = EntryStream.zip(a, b).toMap();
```

Comment: Or without boxing overhead, but less concise: `IntStream.range(0, a.size()).collect(HashMap::new, (m,i)->m.put(a.get(i), b.get(i)), Map::putAll)`